# Use OpenLayers 5 typescript extent.js in Angular 7

Tags: angular, openlayers, openlayers-5

I am trying to use the "extend" function extent.js which is included under "ol" as an independent file in my code.

I tried importing it like this...

```
import olExtent from '../../../../../node_modules/ol/extent.js';
```

but I get an error saying default has not been defined.

Any help in how to use the functions in this file are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your project with npm you won't need to use the full path to the node_modules folder but just `ol/extent`.

Even more important is, that you need to use [named imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module) for the `extend` function, as the `extent` module has no default export.

So the final line should look something like this:

```js
import {extend} from 'ol/extent.js';
```

If you need every function of the extent module yo could also try this:

```js
import * as olExtent from 'ol/extent.js';
```